# Exception in UI \ view in section that is in comment - HTML PHP Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, dom, laravel-5

I have a question, and I am new to laravel and html.
I have a view, and in the view I have a certain code that is in comment.
when I try to load the page it throws exception on this part of code, But why? If I remove the code completely it worked, so why the page loads the comments?

this the code:

```
 <!--  <td> Removed in and not to use
                    <input type="text" class="table-control p-r-20" name="dsp_fee_pct" value="{{$dsp_account['dsp_fee_pct']}}" id="dsp_fee_pct">
                    <span class="table-control-addon-right">%</span>
                </td> -->
```

and this is the exception:
[image]

Comment: It complaints because `$dsp_account` doesn't contain any array element named `dsp_fee_pct`.

Comment: But this line in comment block, why it try to even read it? I just want it not be performed at all

Comment: Because it's a HTML comment. Only clients/browsers cares about that one. Your blade code `{{ $dsp_account['dsp_fee_pct'] }}` gets parsed and executed on the server, before it's even returned to the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try comment like this :

```
{{--  <td>
          <input type="text" class="table-control p-r-20" name="dsp_fee_pct" value="{{$dsp_account['dsp_fee_pct']}}" id="dsp_fee_pct">
          <span class="table-control-addon-right">%</span>
      </td> --}}
```

or change :

```
value="{{ $dsp_account['dsp_fee_pct'] ?? ''}}"
```

Comment: How would that solve an `undefined index` issue?

Comment: modify your input ```value="{{ $dsp_account['dsp_fee_pct'] ?? ''}}"```

Comment: If you realize that your answer doesn't actually answer the question (which is why they get that exception), update the answer instead of giving a different answer as a comment.

Comment: @M.Eriksson, I'm very sorry , I modified it !

Comment: Is their any way to create comments in the html? view in laravel and the Dom just not read them at all? since this is comment just comment not code that I want it to run

Comment: tnx it worked as expcted

Answer (score 0):

thanks this solved it:

```
<!-- this code is in comment and  Removed in
              {{--  <td> 
                    <input type="text" class="table-control p-r-20" name="dsp_fee_pct" value="{{$dsp_account['dsp_fee_pct']}}" id="dsp_fee_pct">
                    <span class="table-control-addon-right">%</span>
                </td> --}} -->
```